# Recovering changes from mercurial attic

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking at an old mercurial repo that has been pulled across some changes of computing environment. In the file `.hg/attic` there are three patch files with changes that were once shelved and left there. I don't have the third-party `attic` extension installed, and would prefer to keep it that way. Could someone tell me how to migrate them to something `hg shelve` can see and manage?

I have mercurial version 4.2, and the shelve extension is enabled. The attic files look like this:

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Joe <email@host>
# Date 1424777770 -3600
# Parent  46fafaab608c9a7bd8768c4b41792f2f21f04d8d
diff --git a/project/sql/createcustom.sql b/project/sql/createcustom.sql
<etc.>
```

Comment: I'm just taking a stab at this, but would it work to run `hg patch --no-commit` followed by `hg shelve` for each attic file? I don't know exactly what other data the attic files have, but the snippet you pasted is just a normal `hg export -g` output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of that but didn't pursue the thought since I'd run into merge conflicts. However, the patches specify the parent revision, so I could update to that, apply them, then shelve them. But it would be nice if there's a more direct way... (There's nothing else in the file, just the header and the diffs.)

Comment: You sure could create a small shell script to do that task for you. But given it's 3 patches, that's not worth the time.

Comment: You're right, and I've already done it. In the end I had to get my hands dirty because one of the base revisions wasn't in the repository anymore, so it took some trial and error and finally working around some merge conflicts.  But it's done now.